# Boxplot placed on time axis

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to place a series of (matplotlib) boxplots in a time axis. They are series of measurements taken on different days along a year. The dates are not evenly distributed and I am interested on the variation along time.

---

### Easy version

I have a pandas DataFrame with indexes and series of numbers, more or less like this: (notice the indexes):

```
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array( [ np.random.normal( i, 1, 10 ) for i in range(3) ] )
ii = np.array([ 3, 5, 8 ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( data=data, index=ii )
```

For each index, I need to make a boxplot, which is no problem:

```
plt.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True, positions=ii )
```

[image]

### Time version

The problem is, I need to place the boxes in a time axis, i.e. place the boxes on a concrete date

```
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array( [ np.random.normal( i, 1, 10 ) for i in range(3) ] )
dates = pd.to_datetime( [ '2015-06-01', '2015-06-15', '2015-08-30' ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( data=data, index=dates )
plt.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True )
```

[image]

However, if I incorporate the positions:

`ax.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True, positions=dates )`

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'float'

A look up on the docs shows:

`plt.boxplot?`

> positions : array-like, default = [1, 2, ..., n]
>
> Sets the positions of the boxes. The ticks and limits are automatically set to match the positions.

---

### Wished time version

This code is intended to clarify, narrow down the problem. The boxes should apppear there, where the blue points are placed in the next figure.

```
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array( [ np.random.normal( i, 1, 10 ) for i in range(3) ] )
dates = pd.to_datetime( [ '2015-06-01', '2015-06-15', '2015-08-30' ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( data=data, index=dates )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(10,5) )
x1 = pd.to_datetime( '2015-05-01' )
x2 = pd.to_datetime( '2015-09-30' )
ax.set_xlim( [ x1, x2 ] )

# ax.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True ) # Does not throw error, but plots nothing (out of range)
# ax.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True, positions=dates ) # This is what I'd like (throws TypeError)

ax.plot( dates, [ df.loc[i].mean() for i in df.index ], 'o' )  # Added to clarify the positions I aim for
```

[image]

---

**Is there a method to place boxplots in a time axis?**

---

I am using:

python: 3.4.3 + numpy: 1.11.0 + pandas: 0.18.0 + matplotlib: 1.5.1

Comment: ***unless*** the dates are your column indices, you can't have them be on the x-axis. Boxplots plot ranges of a given field/column on the y-axis while keeping the name of the field/column on the x-axis. You could plot them horizontally. But the idea remains the same.

Comment: Did you try passing in a list of datetime objects  for `position`?

Comment: It looks like you will need to explicitly pass in a delta time for the `width` kwarg

Comment: @Abdou Of course you can have dates on the x-axis, you can pass them directly: `plt.plot( dates.dt, np.arange(12) )
`

Comment: @Luis That's a plot. Not a boxplot!

Comment: @tcaswell I tried that, get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'float'`

Comment: @Abdou Indeed, but then I did not understand your comment, sorry. Can you explain a bit about the column indices?

Comment: You should include the full trace back in your question

Comment: @Luis: take a look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9nt5favc0tdtg8l/boxplots.py?dl=0). It should show you what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Luis, do you now understand my point?

Comment: which comment do you not understand?

Comment: @tcaswell `You should include the full trace back in your question`

Comment: @Abdou Sorry, only now can I see your link. I see two things in your code: The first is that you use df.boxplot instead of plt.boxplot(df). The second is the use of time as column names for df. Unfortunately, that does not set the position of the boxes on the x-axis, but only set labels for them.

Answer (score 5):

So far, my best solution is to convert the units of the axis into a suitable `int` unit and plot everything accordingly. In my case, those are days.

```
np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array( [ np.random.normal( i, 1, 10 ) for i in range(3) ] )
dates = pd.to_datetime( [ '2015-06-01', '2015-06-15', '2015-08-30' ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( data=data, index=dates )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(10,5) )
x1 = pd.to_datetime( '2015-05-01' )
x2 = pd.to_datetime( '2015-09-30' )
pos = ( dates - x1 ).days

ax.boxplot( [ df.loc[i] for i in df.index ], vert=True, positions=pos )
ax.plot( pos, [ df.loc[i].mean() for i in df.index ], 'o' )

ax.set_xlim( [ 0, (x2-x1).days ] )
ax.set_xticklabels( dates.date, rotation=45 )
```

[image]

The boxplots are placed on their correct position, but the code seems a bit cumbersome to me.

More importantly: The units of the x-axis are not "time" anymore.

Answer (score 3):

this is a quite late answer but i thought that still relevant. Below is my attempt on it

```
import numpy as np[![enter image description here][1]][1]
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array( [ np.random.normal( i, 1, 10 ) for i in range(3) ] )
dates = pd.to_datetime( [ '2015-06-01', '2015-06-15', '2015-08-30' ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( data=data, index=dates )


df.T.boxplot(
        positions=mpl.dates.date2num(df.index),
        widths=5,
        )
ax = plt.gca()
f = plt.gcf()

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The desired output can be generated in two ways. But it is safe to keep in mind that `boxplots` plot ranges of a given field/column on the `y-axis` while keeping the name of the field/column on the `x-axis`. You could plot them horizontally. But the idea remains the same.

At any rate, you can create the dataframe with pandas `timestamp` objects as the column names. That way when you call the boxplot function on your dataframe, the output will show the column names on the `x-axis`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)
data = np.array([np.random.normal(i, 1, 50) for i in range(12)])

##Create an array that will be the names of your columns
ii = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2015-06-01'),periods=data.shape[1], freq='MS')

##Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=ii)

##I am going to reduce the number of columns so that the plot can show
checker = ii[:3]
df[checker].boxplot()

#Show the boxplots. This is just for 3 columns out of 50
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also go with what you had by transposing the dataframe, so that the indices will become the column names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

data = np.array([np.random.normal(i, 1, 50) for i in range(12)])

##Create an array that will be the indices of your dataframe
ii = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2015-06-01'),periods=data.shape[0], freq='MS')

##Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=ii)

##I am going to reduce the number of columns so that the plot can show
checker = ii[:3]
df.T[checker].boxplot()

#Show the boxplots. This is just for 3 columns out of 50
plt.show()
```

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking and thinking about your answer, and there is a problem that I did not realize until now that I fully tested with non-regularly spaced dates. Your method only puts the dates as labels, but does not actually set the *position* of the boxes on the axis.

Comment: I am sorry to have said otherwise in the comments, that was my mistake, but this method does not answer the original question.